# Freeze formula in one cell once date is posted in another cell

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I want to count the number of days it takes to answer a question and then once the question is answered, the number of days is frozen.

For example, B1 is the date the question is received. C1 is the number of days that have elapsed since the question is received. The formula I used for C1 is =TODAY() -b1 & " days". D1 is the date the answer is posted. I want the value in C1 to be frozen on the date that is then posted in D1.

How can I amend the formula to freeze C1 with the value returned by D1-B1 once a date is entered into D1?

B1:Date question received,
C1:Number of days since question was received (or took to answer),
D1:Date question answered

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in C1

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D1),TODAY()-B1,D1-B1) & " days"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because TODAY is a volatile function, in order to freeze the date, you need a macro function to be called when the date is entered in D1, that extract the formula calculation result from C1 and change the D1 value to its calculation result instead of the formula.